# Spell Check my Delphi source code

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, spell-checking

Previously I have used Visual AssistX in Visual Studio and it had a very nice spell checking over literals.

Is there something similar to Visual Assist spell checker present for Delphi as expert?

It should spell check method names, class names and especially resourcestrings and literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use BatchSpellChecker to check the forms and strings

Comment: Eventually decided to go with BatchSpellChecker.

Answer (score 3):

The closest I know of is the Code Proofreader in [GExperts](http://www.gexperts.org/)

Comment: Not quite close to a spelling check over words. More like a formatting check.

Comment: I beg to differ. It can auto-correct misspelled words, based on a dictionary and/or use the compiler. Very useful for mistyped usual names where you hit a nearby key. It can also replace automatically ;= by := in case you typed it wrong...

Comment: I guess that the spell checking on literals is a thing that noone has done so far.

Hey, this means that there is an open market niche!

Comment: Very good idea. Especially if you can wrap it up as a new expert in GExperts :-)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.remotedebugger.com/delphispell.asp
 + integrates into the IDE
 - seems to be stuck at Delphi XE2 (no more updates)
 - $100

http://www.batchspellchecker.com/download
 + supports Delphi files
 - does not integrate in IDE
 + it is $50 (but it also has a lite version)

http://www.addictive-software.com/other-downloads.htm
  + integrates into the IDE
  - abandoned since 2009